# How to store user data on Android to prevent repeated logins?

Tags: android, authentication, sharedpreferences

I want to save user credentials in my Android app until the app is uninstalled. The user enters his/her details in 2 text fields. How can I store these credentials?

Comment: Use [`SharedPreferences`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html).

Comment: but how ? and in what way to use them ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

use below **tutorial**

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-session-management-using-shared-preferences/

<kbd>[shared-preferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)</kbd>

Examples

```
SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences( "any_prefname", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Available mode for shared preference:

```
1)MODE_WORLD_READABLE
2)MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE
3)MODE_PRIVATE
```

**save data** into shared preferences using **editor**

```
     editor.putBoolean("key_name", true); // Storing boolean - true/false
     editor.putString("key_name", "string value"); // Storing string
     editor.putInt("key_name", "int value"); // Storing integer
     editor.putFloat("key_name", "float value"); // Storing float
     editor.putLong("key_name", "long value"); // Storing long
     editor.commit();
```

Call `editor.commit()` in order to **save changes** to shared preferences.

**retrived** from **saved** preferences

```
          pref.getString("key_name", null); // getting String
          pref.getInt("key_name", null); // getting Integer
          pref.getFloat("key_name", null); // getting Float
          pref.getLong("key_name", null); // getting Long
          pref.getBoolean("key_name", null); // getting boolean
```

Refrence from [like](http://androiddeveloperspot.blogspot.in/2013/01/sharedpreference-in-android.html)

Comment: thnx Tamilan..its working for me..

Answer (score 0):

You can use SharedPreferences. A function that saves string values to sharedpref is below:

```
public void saveString(Context c, String prefName, String key, String value){
    SharedPreferences settings = c.getSharedPreferences(prefName, 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putString(key, value);
    editor.commit();
}
```

"context" = your activity's context. "prefName" a value for SharedPref folder you can call any name for it. "key" is the  specific value for it and you will use for loading "String value" in anywhere.

Finally loading from sharedpref method is:

```
public String loadString(Context c, String prefName, String key){
    SharedPreferences settings = c.getSharedPreferences(prefName, 0);
    return settings.getString(key, "");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this code

```
class MyActivity extends Activity{
 //check if we have sharedprefs. else create and store in Utils

   if (MyUtils().getSharedPref() == null) {
    SharedPreferences sp = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    MyUtils.getInstance().setSharedPref(sp);
}

 loadLastKnowLoginInfo(){
String emailStr = MyUtils.getInstance().getLoginEmail();
String passStr = MyUtils.getInstance().getLoginPassword();

//If Previous credentials are empty.. get them from user and store in Sharedprefs. Else Login
if(emailStr.equals(“”) || passStr.equals(“”)){
    //We do not have Login Credentials.
    startLoginProcess();
} else {
    login(emailStr, passStr);
}

}

 private void startLoginProcess(){

//Initialize UI for getting Login Credentials

//Store these credentials in SharedPrefs
MyUtils.getInstance().saveRegularLoginDetails(email, pass);
  }
}


public class MyUtils {

private static volatile MyUtils sharedInstance = null;
    private static String KEY_LOGIN_EMAIL="loginEmail";
private static String KEY_LOGIN_PASS="loginPass";
public static MyUtils getInstance() {
    if (sharedInstance == null) {
        synchronized(MyUtils class) {
            if (sharedInstance == null)
                sharedInstance = new MyUtils();
        }
    }
    return sharedInstance;
}


public void setSharedPref(SharedPreferences sp) {

    _sp = sp;
}

public SharedPreferences getSharedPref(){
    return _sp;
}



public String getLoginEmail() {
    return _sp.getString(KEY_LOGIN_EMAIL, "");
}

public String getLoginPassword() {
    return _sp.getString(KEY_LOGIN_PASS, "");
}



public void saveRegularLoginDetails (String email, String password) {
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = _sp.edit();
    editor.putString(KEY_LOGIN_EMAIL, email);
    editor.putString(KEY_LOGIN_PASS, password);

    editor.commit();
}
}
```